# How to execute curl commands in Selenium tests using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, curl, selenium-webdriver

I need to store output executed from the curl cmd; say,

```
curl -XPOST 'http://xxxx:9200/xxxx/_search' \
     --noproxy \
     -d' {'query':{'bool':{'must':[{'term':{'xxx':xxx}}]}}}'
```

Selenium-binding used: `Ruby`

Comment: Feel free to store it if you need.

Comment: is there any specific command to execute the curl in between selenium tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
definition = "curl -XPOST 'http://xxxx:9200/xxxx/_search' --noproxy -d' {'query':{'bool':{'must':[{'term':{'xxx':xxx}}]}}}'"

JSON.parse(%x(#{definition}))
```